# What do the sources say about internalising the loss of the Beis HaMikdosh?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, churban-destruction, three-weeks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to visualize the Churban Bais HaMikdash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/what-is-the-best-way-to-visualize-the-churban-bais-hamikdash)

It is difficult for me to feel the loss of the Beis HaMikdosh. Even with some of the practical advice provided in the answers [to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9016/759), it would be helpful to know what, if anything, the traditional sources say about internalising the loss and getting the right perspective on the Three Weeks?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9016/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Quite possibly. But I am asking for sourced answers unlike the ones given in your link.

Comment: @DoubleAA and A"Y, how's it now?

Comment: @SethJ Brilliant!

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate. The answers to the older question are all unsourced, but there's no reason it should stay that way. The question does not ask for unsourced answers. Any answer here belongs there, and this question is a subset of that one (exactly the same as that one except that it asks for sources). Am I missing something here? Closing as duplicate for now; feel free to comment further, of course.

Comment: I agree with msh210. If you really want sourced answers, consider a bounty to that question.

Comment: Hmm, I can't really say why I didn't think of the bounty option, but now considering that, I tend to agree with the others above.