# Movie picturing the destruction of the holy temple?

Tags: product-recommendation, beis-hamikdash, chinuch-education, churban-destruction, performance-entertainment

Lately, I have been telling my 3-year-old son about the building, destruction, rebuilding cycle of the *Beis Hamikdash* (holy temple in Jerusalem). He is wondering how it would have looked. Are there any movies or videos that attempt to picture this?

I realize that there is not much (or any?) historical information to rely on in creating such pictures, but for educational purposes of a 3-year-old, anything is fine with me.

Comment: I once saw a video of a tour of the beis hamikdosh, digitalised, but he'd get bored, it's more to teach people the layout of the beis hamikdosh, i believe it was based on the mishnah (middos?). As for destruction, rebuilding..., I've never heard of any such video

Comment: This might be enough for a 3 year old, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Francesco_Hayez_017.jpg/1600px-Francesco_Hayez_017.jpg

Comment: "For educational purposes of a 3-year-old" my understanding of the lubavicher Rebbe's opinion about this is you need to be careful even in educating a 3 year old, not to be more careless becouse of his  young age

Comment: How about any number of [these](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=894&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9&oq=%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30k1l2.17786.23503.0.23582.25.23.2.0.0.0.123.1986.16j5.21.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.20.1745.0..0i67k1.Qu6ALq5GFfQ) pictures.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17063/759

Comment: You could always [build a Beis HaMikdash in Minecraft](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71440/9682) and then drop a boatload of TNT on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XljGbi5PD_g) video doesn't show the destruction of the mikdash, it would probably give your child more of an appreciation of what we lost on Tisha B'Av.

Similar videos can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6oEn0JX9Mk), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-uv487eUX8), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GssY43qv54k).

For drawings of the destruction of the Beis HaMikdash, see [here](http://www.romaikor.hu/image.php?p=jeruzsalem_ostroma_2.jpg), [here](http://72.32.137.209/piction/ump.show_public_image?v_umo=12929127&quality=O4), and [here](http://www.jewishprisoner.com/Images/BM%20first%20Beis%20Hamikdash%20destroyed%20babylon.jpg).