# Jewish Minecraft instructions?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, beis-hamikdash, architecture-design, mishkan-tabernacle

My 8 year old son wants to build a mizbeyach or a simple beit hamikdash structure on Minecraft. I know nothing about Minecraft and he is not great at it, though he uses it a lot. Does anyone know how to do this or where we can find instructions? With many thanks!

Comment: Mishnah Tractate Middot should be a good starting place.

Comment: Gabrielle Lebens, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! May your son meet with much success in this project, and may he go on to participate in building the real thing. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0XuZTT2aVY) is a YouTube video of someone's actual Minecraft model of the (first) Beit Hamikdash.

If building based on that isn't enough, they provide some links in the video description. Disclaimer: I don't do Minecraft and have no idea if these links will help.
[Map](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qm2cetk0llsauyp/Beit+HaMikadash.zip), [Skin](http://adf.ly/I4QPw), [Interactive tour](http://adf.ly/dMJ3a)
Some comments there suggest a few improvements (quartz?) which you may want to take into account.

Best of luck!

Comment: That's the second temple btw. I built the first temple back in the beta days. http://imgur.com/a/RsLCw

Answer (score 2):

Well... This is certainly unexpected. I never thought I'd ever see a question on here about Minecraft. It's really true that you can take anything and use it for Torah.

I'd start with picking a scale. Keep in mind that each block is a cubic meter, so you can increase or decrease that proportion to amos however you'd like.

Once he's decided on that, figure out which version he wants to build. The parts of the Mishkan are described in Terumah and Vayakhel, but a few keilim made their way into Tetzaveh and Ki Sisa also. If you want to build the Bayis Rishon, that's all recorded in Melachim Aleph 7. Bayis Sheini, as Ephraim pointed out, is described in Maseches Middos.

From there, things are fairly straightforward. Wool, gold, and dirt are all standard in the game. For copper, he can try to get away with gold, but I'd recommend putting mods in the game to help make the copper look better. (If you Google "Minecraft Forge install" you'll find the link to be able to install the software to allow you to mod your Minecraft.) Those are the only materials I can think of off the top of my head that come up often.

If he really wants to get really creative, he can make a command block under the Kodesh Kadashim that teleports you back a few blocks if you try to enter. You know, since the lead doesn't attach to players, and it's certainly a lot better if your Steve comes out not dead.

Hatzlacha Rabbah. Make sure to warn him that he might be getting in a little over his head; oftentimes Minecraft can get really complicated really quickly. If he goes through with it, I'd love to see it when it's done. :)