# Are movies allowed in Tishe bAv?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, tisha-bav

i realised some of shuls,including Orthodox and Chabad, will air flims on Tisha bAv, after the fast starts. They included films about topics like fighting got Eretz Yisrael.
What is the halacha about movies on 9 Av?

Comment: I don't know why there was a downvote. It seems like a fair, clear question. Offhand, it seems that shuls show videos that are somehow related to tragedy and Tisha B'Av. Most of the "videos" are actually lectures / *shiurim*, so I wouldn't consider these "movies", really. However, I know on eshul in my neighborhood is showing a film about some "Heroes of the Holocaust". While the Holocaust, itself, was tragic, I'm not sure if this type of film may be really within the Tisha B'Av spirit.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29591 . See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62212

Comment: I think that a bigger problem may be the realm of shiurim given on Tisha B'Av in many communities. While the topics may be appropriate, the gathering of a large crowd of people to come to some of these shiurim creates a light-hearted mood, somewhat similar to what goes on at the Kotel on Tisha B'Av night.

Comment: The related questions are not specific enough for my inquiry but thanks. I myself didn't feel comfortable to join a large crowd for a movie, there is inevitable schmoozing since you can't be sure everyone incl oneself's a tzadik and won't try to chit-chat. I don't understand why we can't just all sit down and read some aggadot about the chorban shel Beth HaMikdash, so I wonder what the halacha really is. Wish someone would have an answer